# Elasticsearch - Index Mapping settings for both exact and partial matching

Tags: indexing, tokenize, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm new to elasticsearch and am trying to learn how to index using optimal mapping settings to achieve the following.

If I have a document like this

```
{"name":"Galapagos Islands"}
```

I want to get this a result for both the following queries

**1) Partial matching**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "ga"
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Exact matching**

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "name": "Galapagos Islands"
        }
    }
}
```

With the setting I have currently. I am able to achieve the partial matching part. But exact matching returns no results. Please find below the settings with which I indexed.

```
{
  "mappings": {
        "islands": {
            "properties": {
                "name":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "search_ngram"
                }
            }
        }
    },

  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "autocomplete":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ] 
        },
        "search_ngram": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "ngram":{
          "type":"ngram",
          "min_gram":2,
          "max_gram":15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to do exact matching and partial matching on a field ?

**UPDATE**

After recreating the index with settings given below. My mappings look like this

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testing/_mappings?pretty'
{
  "testing" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "islands" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index_analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "search_ngram",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My indexing settings are the below

```
{
  "mappings": {
        "islands": {
            "properties": {
                "name":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "search_ngram",
                    "fields": {
                      "raw": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "autocomplete":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ] 
        },
        "search_ngram": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        },
        "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "ngram":{
          "type":"ngram",
          "min_gram":2,
          "max_gram":15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And with all the above, when I query like this

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testing/islands/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"term": {"name.raw" : "Galapagos Islands"}}}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

And My document is this

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testing/islands/1?pretty'
{
  "_index" : "testing",
  "_type" : "islands",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"name":"Galapagos Islands"}
}
```

Comment: Your mapping, test data and queries all work for me. Are you sure you tested this properly?

Comment: What do you get if you run `GET /index_name/islands/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "name"
  ]
}` ?

Comment: After your update to the ticket, it makes sense :-). And my answer below stands.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Please find the fielddatafields query output above

Comment: My request with `fielddata_fields` made sense with your initial post. Now that you updated it with the correct query, I don't need it anymore. Try my suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a subfield to your `name` property which should be `not_analyzed`. Or, if you care about lowercase/uppercase, a `keyword` tokenizer together with a `lowercase` filter.

This should index `Galapagos` as is, not modifications. Then you can do your `term` search.

For example, a `keyword` analyzer together with `lowercase` filter:

```
    "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "keyword"
    }
```

And the mapping:

```
        "properties": {
            "name":{
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "search_ngram",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The query to be used is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "name.raw": "galapagos islands"
        }
    }
}
```

So, instead of using the same field - `name` - you should be using `name.raw` (the subfield).

Comment: Hi @Andrei, Thanks for responding to my query quickly. I recreated my index with the above settings. But I can't search for the term "Galapagos Islands". The query I'm using is {"query": {"term": {"name" : "Galapagos Islands"}}}

Comment: Hi Andrei, I double checked everything and added to my question. It doesn't seem to work for me :-(

Comment: My bad. My analyzer will lowercase the values. You have two options: use `"galapagos islands"` in your search (lowercase): `"term": {
            "name.raw": "galapagos islands"
        }` - or change the mapping to something like this: `"fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }` and use `"Galapagos Islands"` when searching: `"term": {
            "name.raw": "Galapagos Islands"
        }`